# Keyword meta tags to work with Google

Tags: wordpress, google, seo, meta-tags

I'm trying to optimize my [website](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) for better search results, I currently have a meta tag created for keywords like so:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="key1, key2, key3" />
```

I have waited 30 days and still when I search my keywords, my site does not come up. How should I be writing my keywords for better results?

My website is based on WordPress.

Comment: Google doesn't take into account the keywords meta tag for SEO! Please specify if your website is indexed by Google or not. Also share your URL.

Answer (score 6):

Google does not use the keywords meta tag in web ranking, [read this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) - it's official, straight from Google.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a feature "Search engine allow". If that is blocked. Then Google can't search your site with meta key words. Go to "Settings" → "Reading" then uncheck "Search Engine Visibility".

Answer (score 1):

Search engine optimization is not just using keywords in the meta-tags.

There are many factors. Here's a short list of where you want to use your keywords. (Don't spam it though.)

1. Title
2. URL
3. domain
4. H1
5. h2
6. in the context
7. alt and title attributes

Answer (score 0):

For your site to be found by people searching in Google and to monitor that, do the following:

- In the WordPress dashboard go to **Settings > Reading** and make sure
  that under **Site Visibility** you have chosen **Allow search engines
  to index this site**
- Register to Webmaster Tools at
  http://www.google.com/webmasters/. Once you add your domain, you
  will be able to Ask Google to crawl a page or site. It allows other things too like monitor your site,submit a sitemap,...
- You could install [XML Sitemap Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) WordPress Plugin and
  then submit that sitemap in WebMaster Tools.
- To monitor activity on your site register at [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

And few words regarding `meta name="keywords"`:

As far as I know that meta doesn't do anything. Only meta that matter is `meta name="description"` and even that is only used to show description of your site when it lands in search results.